# Common block usage in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran-common-block

I'm new to Fortran and just doing some simple things for work. And as a new programmer in general, not sure exactly how this works, so excuse me if my explanation or notation is not the best.  At the top of the .F file there are common declarations.  The person explaining it to me said think of it like a struct in C, and that they are global.  Also in that same .F file, they have it declared with what type.  So it's something like:

```
COMMON SOMEVAR

INTEGER*2 SOMEVAR
```

And then when I actually see it being used in some other file, they declare local variables, (e.g. SOMEVAR_LOCAL) and depending on the condition, they set SOMEVAR_LOCAL = 1  or 0.

Then there is another conditional later down the line that will say something like

```
IF (SOMEVAR_LOCAL. eq. 1) 
SOMEVAR(PARAM) = 1;
```

(Again I apologize if this is not proper Fortran, but I don't have access to the code right now).  So it seems to me that there is a "struct" like variable called SOMEVAR that is of some length (2 bytes of data?), then there is a local variable that is used as a flag so that later down the line, the global struct SOMEVAR can be set to that value.  But because there is (PARAM), it's like an array for that particular instance?  Thanks.  Sorry for my bad explanation, but hopefully you will understand what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first declaration has SOMEVAR as a scalar integer of two bytes.   The usage you show has SOMEVAR has an array -- based on it being indexed.   This is possible to do in Fortran via "sequence association" but it is poor practice.    In one file you could declare SOMEVAR as INTEGER*2 and two bytes are allocated to this scalar.   In another file you could declare it as INTEGER*1 SOMEVAR(2), and two bytes are reserved, this time for an array of two elements, each of one byte.   Using the same common block in both files can cause these two variables to overlap, byte by byte -- sequence association.  Many years ago, when memory was very small, programmers did this to reduce memory usage, knowing that different subroutines were using variables at different times.   The reasons to do this today are very, very limited.   Mostly one shouldn't because it is liable to be confusing.

You can also setup sequence association with the EQUIVALENCE statement.  Again, best avoided.  The modern replacement for the times that one must do "tricky" things that needed the EQUIVALENCE statement is the TRANSFER function.

Answer (score 2):

Just to amplify something @MSB already mentioned: COMMON blocks tell a compiler how to lay variables out in memory.  There is almost no reason to use them with modern Fortran, ie with any compiler which can cope with Fortran 90 or later, and there are good reasons to avoid them.

And to add one thing: in modern Fortran you can do approximately what C structs do with user defined types.  Check your documentation for TYPE.

Comment: I fully agree.  For global variables, with new Fortran programs it is better to use module variables instead of common blocks.  Certain variables cannot be placed in common blocks, and sequence association is archaic.  And TYPE is a much better approach to organizing variables than common, and closer to C structs.